# compiling rJava on Ubuntu

Tags: java, rjava

I am unable to compile rJava from source. Configure is not creating a Makefile even though it says it is.

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating run
config.status: creating src/config.h
drew@drew-ThinkPad-T410:~/Downloads/rJava$ ls
config.log     configure.ac   getsp.class  install-sh  NAMESPACE  src
config.status  configure.win  getsp.java   jri         NEWS       version
configure      DESCRIPTION    inst         man         R
drew@drew-ThinkPad-T410:~/Downloads/rJava$ sudo make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
drew@drew-ThinkPad-T410:~/Downloads/rJava$
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 
./configure
./install-sh

Comment: I tried it. Not sure why you suggest running a compile and bash script in the same line. The two have nothing to do with each other. Thanks for the suggestion though.